# System.DIINotFoundException: Failed to find library "leptonica-1.80.0.dll" for platform x86

Tags: winforms, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, tesseract, leptonica

I'm running an automated application in WinForms and using Tesseract, when I run on localhost it works perfectly, but when I publish or export the `bin` folder to another computer, it shows me this error:

```
System.DIINotFoundException: Failed to find library "leptonica-1.80.0.dll" for platform x86.

in InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(String fileName, String platformName)

in
Interop Runtimelmplementer.LeptonicaApiSignaturesInstance.Leptonica ApiSignaturesImplementation..ctor(LibraryLoader loader)
```

1. I already tried to move it to `myproject\packages\Tesseract.4.1.1\lib\net45\leptonika-1.80.0.dll.` unsuccessfully
2. already checked .NET versions
3. I already tried to install the tesseract package in the project's bin folder

Answer (score 5):

Install vc_redist.x86. It worked for me.

Comment: this seems to have fixed it for me aswell.

Comment: Worked for me too, shame it took me hours before finding this post.

You can find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling tesseract dependency in Visual Studio worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I eventually tracked to down to the following line in a user control:

```
InitializeComponent();

Font font = new Font(new FontFamily("Tahoma"), 9.0F, FontStyle.Regular); // <-- Culprit
```

I fixed it by postponing the font initialization until after the control is loaded...

```
this.Load += delegate {
    Font font = new Font(new FontFamily("Tahoma"), 9.0F, FontStyle.Regular);
};
```