# C# - Class Library - TESSERACT - Failed to find library "leptonica-1.80.0.dll" for platform x86

Tags: c#, tesseract, uipath

I'm writing an activity component to include as nuget package in UiPath.

Here structure:

```
└─lib
  └─net
    ├─(dll developed)
    ├─Tesseract.dll
    ├─x64
    │ ├─leptonica-1.80.0.dll
    │ └─tesseract41.dll
    ├─x86
    │ ├─leptonica-1.80.0.dll
    │ └─tesseract41.dll
    └─tessdata
      ├─osd.traineddata
      ├─ita.traineddata
      └─oci.traineddata
```

With a test app on visual studio, library works.

When I try to run it from UiPath I receive below message, that I collected using visual studio debugger.

Failed to find library "leptonica-1.80.0.dll" for platform x86.

Library has been build with "Any" and "x86" build target, no changes on structure (as output of builder) and no change to error.

Has someone suggestion to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "leptonica-1.80.0.dll" library into project folder and uipath studio dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. In my case it was resolved by "postponing" font initialization in a user control. See answer here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75637319/9717257